HashiCorp Transit Engine, what permission are required to read the public key?
I have a docker-compose that setup HashiCorp Vault and Vault Agent services.
Then I have a script that setup a Transit engine and a key.
The script creates the policy to the transit key and add it to the role of the token.
Using the token as credential I need to get the transit key.
I get the error 403 "1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n".
With a wrong token I have  403  "permission denied", also using the token I'm able to login in the UI. That proves the token is working as credentials.
Using the rootToken I get the 200 success result.
So, problem seems related to permissions/policies.
In the Docker compose I use this to set the Agent:
   command: [ 'vault', 'agent', '-config=/volumes/vault-agent-localhost/config.txt'] 
config.txt:
pid_file = "/volumes/vault-agent/pidfile"

vault {
  address = "http://vault:8200"
}

auto_auth {
  method {
    type = "approle"
    config = {
      role_id_file_path                   = "/volumes/vault-agent/role-id"
      secret_id_file_path                 = "/volumes/vault-agent/secret-id"
      remove_secret_id_file_after_reading = false
    }
  }

  sink {
    type = "file"
    config = {
      path = "/volumes/vault-agent/token"
    }
  }
}

the seatup.sh script:
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8210'
export VAULT_TOKEN='rootToken'


# setup AppRole
vault auth enable approle


# update is required to call "sign" !!
policy='path "transit-local/*" { capabilities = ["read", "update"] } '

# create policy ("-" mean it read from std-in)
echo $policy | vault policy write myapp -

vault write auth/approle/role/my-role \
    role_id="my-role" \
    token_policies="myapp" \
    token_ttl=120m \
    token_max_ttl=120m \
    secret_id_num_uses=0

# this solved the error: error getting path or data from method: error="no known secret ID"
vault write -f -field=secret_id auth/approle/role/my-role/secret-id > volumes/vault-agent/secret-id


# Create the transit engine (if not exists)
vault write sys/mounts/transit-local type=transit path=transit-local

# create a new Ed25519 key 
key_name="my-key-ed25519"
vault write -f transit-local/keys/$key_name type=ed25519

If I login the UI with rootToken I can see the transit-local path, and the key inside it.
If I login the UI with generated token I cannot see the transit-local path.
In the UI Policies section, I can see "myapp" and if I open it I can see the policies:
path "transit-local/*" { capabilities = ["read", "update"] } 

What is missing here ? why that token is not getting the permission?
** [Update] **
I'm using the Read endpoint (https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/transit#read-key)  that is NOT returning the secret key.
For Ed25519 key type it returns something like this (extract):
        "keys": {
            "1": {
                "creation_time": "2023-06-03T09:00:33.940999141Z",
                "name": "ed25519",
                "public_key": "kAD**************************cw="
            }
        },
        "latest_version": 1,

Using the latest version I can get the right public key (Base64 format).
There is no other endpoints that allow to get the public key (at least, I haven't found).
[Update 2]
Output of vault token lookup:
---                  -----
accessor             9aTi***DwU
creation_time        1717405261
creation_ttl         768h
display_name         approle
entity_id            9a19ad41-da28-22f5-7161-018c6b4b8af7
expire_time          2024-07-05T09:01:01.486433609Z
explicit_max_ttl     0s
id                   hvs.CAES***reEw
issue_time           2024-06-03T09:01:01.480247932Z
last_renewal         2024-06-03T09:01:01.486433709Z
last_renewal_time    1717405261
meta                 map[role_name:my-role]
num_uses             0
orphan               true
path                 auth/approle/login
policies             [default]
renewable            true
ttl                  761h50m56s
type                 service

Token is the one stored in /volume/.../token. :OK.
"num_uses: 0" does not seems correct.
"policies: [default]" does not seems correct neither.
** [Update-3] **
I'm not sure the vault command is always using the right address (I've no errors running the script, and the other Vault at 8200 is down to avoid false result) because it seems like for some commands (like calling "vault read" from the console) I have to pass the -address parameter, otherwise the error says the key was not found at 127.0.0.1:8200... while it should use 8210, as specified with export VAULT_ADDR.
Maybe is just a problem in the last test I did in the console.
Another detail: I'm using GitBash in Windows. I have this alias set:
alias vault="/c/Data/Tools/Hashicorp\ Vault/vault.exe" 
so I just use "vault" command in GitBash shell.
** [Update 4] **
The 2 services are setup with Docker Compose.
Since another application has already a Vault exposed on default 8200, here I had to expose the Vault on 8210.
networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network

services:
  vault:
    container_name: my-vault
    hostname: vault
    image: hashicorp/vault:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: ["vault", "server", "-dev", "-dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:8200"]
    environment:
      VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: rootToken
      VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/vault/file:/vault/file
      - ./volumes/vault/logs:/vault/logs
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ports:
      # 8200 is used by another Vault
      - "8210:8200"  # Map container port 8200 (UI) to host port 8210
    networks:
      - my-network

  vaultagent:
    depends_on: [vault]      
    container_name: my-vaultagent
    image: hashicorp/vault:latest
    restart: always
    command: [ 'vault', 'agent', '-config=/volumes/vault-agent-localhost/config.txt']
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/vault-agent-localhost:/volumes/vault-agent-localhost
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    networks:
      - my-network


How do you send the secret_id to Vault Agent ? Could it be that it is not authenticated at all? Running the same configuration as your question (but outside of Docker) and logging in with the AppRole I can read the key with vault read --field keys --format json transit-local/keys/my-key-ed25519. Can you add a vault token lookup right before the agent gets the key? If you get access denied, that means the agent is not logged in.

vault read -address=http://localhost:8210 --field keys --format json transit-local/keys/$key_name works (I expose the Vault on port 8210, because 8200 is used by another Vault of another project).
That proves the key is set properly.
If I change export VAULT_TOKEN='<generated token>'  I get " 403 . * 1 error occurred:
* permission denied"
 is the one the Agent store in "/volume/.../token".
The issue is only with set up  token/role, not "rootToken".

Can you run vault token lookup in the context of the agent? It will tell you that the login is valid and the policies are applied as expected without deduding from the login's side effects.

vault token lookup:
creation_time        1717405261
creation_ttl         768h
display_name         approle
expire_time          2024-07-05T09:01:01.486433609Z
id                   hvs.CAES***p3UHVreEw
issue_time           2024-06-03T09:01:01
last_renewal         2024-06-03T09:01:01
last_renewal_time    1717405261
meta                 map[role_name:my-role]
num_uses             0
orphan               true
path                 auth/approle/login
policies             [default]
renewable            true
ttl                  761h50m56s
type                 service

Added output to the question, under "Update-2".
num_uses             0 and policies             [default] are ok ?

In Vault UI I can see under Policies: "default", "myapp", "root" (this one is greyed).
the policy I set is in "myapp".
I added it to £"default" and I can read the token !
So, is the association of the policy to the token not done properly. (or the role to the token).
path "transit-local/*" { capabilities = ["read", "update"] }

In a prevous test I was set both:
token_policies="myapp" and policies="myapp" but (also with the help of AI) I read the right one is token_policies (and is the one used in another working application I'm copying a little bit this stuff).

The other application is setting the policy using an external file, while I'm passing it directly in the script.
vault policy write another-app./volumes/vault/another-app-role-policy.hcl
Since the policy is created (I can see and edit) I believe there are no differences on doing it in this way.

The comments thread below your question shows that the myapp policy is not applied to the AppRole's token.
The agent uses address = "http://vault:8200", but your configuration script uses export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8210'.
Assuming the vault hostname resolves to the Vault that is running on localhost, change the port in config.txt from 8200 to 8210 (or make whatever changes are required to reach the instance where the policy is).

The 2 containers are on the same Docker network (I use Docker Compose), so it can reach it "directly" on 8200. But the Vault is exposed on 8210
  ports:  - "8210:8200"
When I run the script, I point to the Vault EXPOSED port of the container because from the guest point of view the Vault API are exposed on 8210.
Changing address to localhost:8200, the Vault Agent cannot reach 8210
error authenticating: error="Put \"http://localhost:8210/v1/auth/approle/login\": dial tcp [::1]:8210: connect: connection refused" 
That proves that 8200 is correct there.

     role_id_file_path                   = "/volumes/vault-agent-localhost/role-id"       secret_id_file_path                 = "/volumes/vault-agent-localhost/secret-id"
secret-id    file contains a random GUID, is it correct?
role-id   contains "my-role"   (Visual Studio added an extra line. removed: issue still there)

Recreated the files (new GUID for secret and role) restarted everything... it finally works.
I'm trying to figure out what actually changed... but it seems like the only change in GIT is this line: policy='path "transit-local/*" { capabilities = ["read", "update"] }'
... there was an extra space after the closing curly brackets.
I'm literally too tired to verify this now.
(I really suspect was the extra lien added by code style to the role_id file content)
Your suggestions, especially the one for token lookup were fundamental to solve this, THANK YOU.
